# C standard input/output by line

Tags: c, input, output, standards

I'm completely new to C and I'm trying to write a small program that reads standard input and copies it to standard output. We were given the functions readline and writeline, which I'm supposed to use for this task. I keep getting a bunch of errors but I don't know how to interpret or fix them, could someone help me out?

Here are the errors I get:

```
lfcopy.c: In function ‘main’:
lfcopy.c:11: error: expected expression before ‘char’
lfcopy.c:11: error: too few arguments to function ‘readline’
lfcopy.c:12: error: expected expression before ‘const’
cc1: warnings being treated as errors
lfcopy.c:9: warning: unused variable ‘max’
```

And here is my file lfcopy:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int readline(char line[], int max);
int writeline(const char line[]);

int main(){
   int c;
   int max = 100;


   while ((c = readline(char line[], max)) != 0)
      writeline(const char line[]);

   return 0;
}

/* readline: read a line from standard input, return its
 * length or 0
 * */
int readline(char line[], int max)
{
   if (fgets(line, max, stdin) == NULL)
      return 0;
   else
      return strlen(line);
}
/* writeline: write line to standard output, return number of chars
 * written */
int writeline(const char line[])
{
   fputs(line, stdout);
   return strlen(line);
}
```

Comment: `while ((c = readline(char line[], max)) != 0)
      writeline(const char line[]);` --> `char line[max]; while ((c = readline(line, max)) != 0)
      writeline(line);`